# Ease of reduction of carboxylic acid derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

Lithium aluminium hydride (LAH) is able to reduce aldehydes, ketones, carboxylic acids and esters. However, sodium borohyride ($\ce{NaBH4}$) is unable to reduce carboxylic acids and esters. Given that LAH is a stronger reducing agent than $\ce{NaBH4}$, it can be inferred that carboxylic acids and esters are more resistant to reduction than aldehydes and ketones. Why is this so?

Comment: Well, resonance comes to mind as basic rationalisation for this.

Comment: Mithoron, I'm not sure how resonance has a part to play here. Could you elaborate a bit further? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I guess otherwise you'd not ask... So called resonance is rationalisation for relatively low enthalpy of formation of compounds.  If compound is "lower on energy" then it is less reactive, because reaction provides also less energy.

Comment: So the reason why carboxylic acids and esters are less reactive is because of the stability on them conferred by resonance?

Comment: Less reactive in reactions, which break resonance.